# translate_user_role doesn't work

Tags: user-roles, translation, localization

I did dozens of tests, this is the code that I am tring to make work:

```
$user = get_userdata($user_ID);
    /* WE NEED TO REMOVE BBP ROLES */
    $roles = array();
    global $wp_roles;
    foreach ($user->roles as $key => $role) {
       if (substr($role, 0, 4) != 'bbp_') {
          array_push($roles, translate_user_role($wp_roles->role_names[$role]));
       }
   }
```

I replaced the parameter passed to translate_user_role with a lot of others but nothing works, neither just:

```
translate_user_role('Administrator');
```

or

```
translate_user_role('administrator');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `translate_user_role` doesn't work in the front-end currently.

Here is a workaround, you can place this in your theme:

```
add_action( 'init', 'load_admin_textdomain_in_front' )
function load_admin_textdomain_in_front() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        load_textdomain( 'default', WP_LANG_DIR . '/admin-' . get_locale() . '.mo' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @JoryHogeveen, thank you for your reply, actually I still need it, so sorry for my long delay as well.

I added this code but the role names are not translated yet, maybe is the way I get them, I am trying to insert some roles in an array, I did many tests, such as:

`array_push($roles, __($wp_roles->roles[$role]['name'], 'default'));` or `array_push($roles, $wp_roles->roles[$role]['name']);`

Comment: Hi @Antonio, never got a notice of your comment, sorry.
You can get all role names with `$wp_roles->role_names`.
Small example to add all roles translated: `array_push( $roles, array_map( 'translate_user_role', $wp_roles->role_names ) )`
Hope this comment still helps! Edit: Oh, and please accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Hello @Jory, thank you so much for your reply, it's still helpful actually. I did another test and I've noticed that now your first reply is enough to translate the roles on the frontend, now I can use `translate_user_role($wp_roles->roles[$role]['name']);` and it takes effect.
Thank you so much!